# How to selectively export in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to selectively export a part of a third party library class. Lets say I have following code files:

```
// File: a.dart, in package test_proj
class A {
}
class A1{
}
```

Another file:

```
// File: index.dart, in package test_proj
// -- option 1, How to do this?
import 'a.dart';
export A; 

// Option 2, How to do this?
export 'a.dart' show A; 

class B {
}
```

Outside the package, I want to reference onlu `A` and `B` and should not get class `A1` from `test_proj/index.dart`

```
import 'package:test_proj/index.dart';

// Should have reference to `A` and `B`.
```

Here both options (1, 2) will give compiler errors. So, what is best solution to this?

Comment: Does it mean you like to hide `A1` class outside the package ?

Comment: I don't want to modify class `A` within package. But from middle-package I want to expose only particular classes from `test_proj`

Answer (score 0):

To hide class outside the package, you can use `protected` meta data.

Firstly add `meta` package on your `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  meta: ^1.7.0 #use latest/compatable one
```

Then add `@protected` before the class you like to hide outside the package.

```
@protected
class A1 {}
```

Comment: I can't modify package `test_proj`. Consider `index.dart` may be in different package from where I want to expose `A` but not `A1`.